# How do I return a character array from char *functionName(int arrayname[SIZE]);

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, char

Assignment: Write a function that assumes the UPC code is an audio/video product, and returns a string indicating which product it is. this is the last function i have to write for this lab and I'm having trouble figuring out how to return a character array from this function. Barcode array is a 12 digit upc code entered by the user and the 10 space in the array indicated which type of media it is. After checking what the digit is, I want to return the indicated character array back to main to be printed.

```
 char *getAudioVideoProductString(int barcodeArray[12]);

 int main()
 { 
    int barcodeArray[12];

    do{
        printf("\nEnter UPC code: ");
        for(i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            {
             scanf("%d", &barcodeArray[i]);
            }
        avstring = getAudioVideoProductString(barcodeArray);
        for(a = 0; a != '\0'; a++)
            {
             printf("%c", avstring[a]);
            }

        printf("\nAdd another UPC code [1 = add, 0 = quit]\n");
        scanf("%d",&end);
       }while(end !=0);

 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}




char *getAudioVideoProductString(int barcodeArray[12])
{
            int i;

    if (barcodeArray[10] == 1)
    {
            char b[] = "12\"\ LP or Single";
            int lengthb = strlen(b);
            char a[] = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
            for (i = 0; i < lengthb; i++)
         {
            a[i] = b[i];
         }
    }

   if (barcodeArray[10] == 0| barcodeArray[10] == 3| barcodeArray[10] == 6)
    {
            char b[] = "Unassigned Audio Format";
            int lengthb = strlen(b);
            char a[] = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
            for (i = 0; i < lengthb; i++)
         {
            a[i] = b[i];
         }
    }
    return a;
}
```

When I compile the program  I get these errors:

[image: Error messages after compiling]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
char a[] = malloc(sizeof(char)*100); //-<< wrong a is not the pointer only the array

char *a = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);  // -<< correct. you need the pointer to assign the address of the allocated memory
```

I think you need to read a bit about the arrays and pointers. Here on the SO are many topics about them. Just search.

PS
if you need the array:

```
char a[100];
```